# Combining two series with different indices and retain only the intersection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two series objects (XVar and YVar) with different indices.

I want to create a dataframe with the intersection of both series objects based on the index of XVar

YVar

```
Name
1995-03    0.042365
1995-04    0.048894
1995-05    0.016465
1995-06    0.041724
1995-07    0.009067
1995-08   -0.018166
1995-09   -0.026390
1995-10    0.022338
1995-11    0.037427
1995-12    0.071605
...
Name: YVar, dtype: float64
```

XVar

```
Name
1995-02    84.9   
1995-05    85.2
1995-08    84.1
1995-11    83.7
...
Name: XVar, dtype: float64
```

Desired output should look like this

```
           XVar    YVar
1995-05    85.2    0.016465
1995-08    84.1   -0.018166
1995-11    83.7    0.037427
...
```

I tried to do it using pd.concat. However, the output only contains XVar...

```
XVar_YVar = pd.concat([XVar, YVar], join = 'inner')
```

What am I missing here?

Best
rentec

Comment: `XVar_YVar = pd.concat([XVar, YVar], join = 'inner', axis=1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` would be a better choice here:

```
pd.DataFrame(XVar).join(pd.DataFrame(YVar), how='inner')
```

should give the expected result;